# One question about the tensor product of $L^1(G)$ and a Banach space $A$

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, tensor-products, banach-algebras

We know that the tensor product of $L^1(G)$ and a Banach space $A$ is isometric to $L^1(G, A)$, the space of all Bochner-integrable $A$-valued functions on a locally compact group $G$. I am looking for a proof of this fact but I cannot find it. Does anyone have proof of it?

Comment: Also asked here at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397872/one-question-about-tensor-product-of-l1g-and-a-banach-space-a.

Comment: Would you please confirm that my answer is fine?

Comment: @hosain: if you are satisfied with the answer then you should click the "tick" symbol to mark the question as "solved", so that it does not stay marked as "unsolved"

Answer (score 3):

Of course you mean the [projective tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product#Cross_norms_and_tensor_products_of_Banach_spaces). See Example 2.19 on p. 29. in

> R. A. Ryan. *Introduction to tensor products of Banach spaces*. Springer Monographs
>   in Mathematics. Springer-Verlag London Ltd., London, 2002.

Comment: Excuse me Tomek thanks for your answer. That is fine.